# Linear algebra prerequisites for abstract algebraic geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I'm interested in what linear/multilinear algebra does one need to study algebraic geometry(following EGA and Harthshorne).
Texts I have in mind are like "Foundations of algebraic geometry" by Ravi Vakil.(If you know how much linear algebra this special book assumes, feel free to tell).
I know you need abstract algebra to tackle algebraic geometry, specifically, ring theory, category theory and some homological algebra.

I'm not interested in classical algebraic geometry, that is, pre-scheme-theoretic algebraic geometry, thought I understand some think it is a natural way to start with this.

Comment: The book of Ravi Vakil has a preface for the reader, where everything is explained how to study the book, and what you should know. Then $764$ pages follow. Linear Algebra is, I think, implicitly assumed, even though not used too much. There are enough other prerequisites, so don't worry about linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you call linear algebra : usually this means working over a field.

To learn algebraic geometry, you will need a reasonably solid background in commutative algebra, meaning (commutative) rings and modules, including some basics of homological algebra.

You should at least know about modules and algebras, tensor products, quotients, localization. Being at ease with the language of categories is also important.

Comment: What I mean are like topics featured in Chapters 2,3 of Bourbaki's Algebra book.
Or something like S.Roman's ''Advanced Linear Algebra"
Module and vector spaces theory. Subspaces(submodules), linear dependence and independence. Linear mappings/ homomorphisms. Matrices. Operators/endomorphisms of vector spaces/modules. Determinant. Exterior, symmetric and tensor algebras.  Something like that, but, please, look at tables of contants of the aformentioned books, if it's not a big deal.